# playframework integration with fbconnect

Tags: playframework, fbconnect

I installed the playframework fbconnect module (version 0.6). I keep getting the following error. 
I am following the steps of the basic example. Even the sample-and-test application in the module folder gives the same error.

```
Compilation error
The file {module:..}/app/controllers/FBConnect.java could not be compiled. Error raised is : play.modules.fbconnect.FBConnectPlugin cannot be resolved

play.exceptions.CompilationException: play.modules.fbconnect.FBConnectPlugin cannot be resolved
    at play.classloading.ApplicationCompiler$2.acceptResult(ApplicationCompiler.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.handleInternalException(Compiler.java:676)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:520)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationCompiler.compile(ApplicationCompiler.java:282)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.getAllClasses(ApplicationClassloader.java:424)
    at play.Play.start(Play.java:505)
    at play.Play.detectChanges(Play.java:629)
    at play.Invoker$Invocation.init(Invoker.java:198)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
```

Comment: How did you install the fbconnect module? Have you added fbconnect as a dependency of your Play! application?

Comment: Yes I installed the play module with the command play install fbconnect-0.6 (I also tried fbconnect-head). I had the dependency to the module in dependency.yaml file and defined the application parameters as described in the README.md.

Comment: And you've added fbconnect to dependencies.yml?

Comment: Yes I did added fbconnect to dependencies.yml

Comment: And you've executed 'play dependencies' to update the dependencies on your project? (I'm not sure of the syntax of this, would have to check, but it's something like that, I think...)

Comment: Yeah I did and retried again just about a minute ago. Same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ouch! It seems that fbconnect-0.6 doesn't correctly install itself in Play! Here's how I got it working:

(my Play! directory is `/usr/local/share/play-1.2.4`)

```
cd /usr/local/share/play-1.2.4/modules
sudo git clone git://github.com/murz/play-fbconnect.git
sudo mv play-fbconnect fbconnect-0.6
```

Now we've got the proper fbconnect-0.6 downloaded in place in Play! We still need to build it, though:

```
cd fbconnect-0.6
sudo vim build.xml
```

(or use any other editor you like :-) ) Add the `<property ..>` element so that the `build.xml` starts like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project name="fbconnect" default="build" basedir=".">
    <property name="play.path" location="/usr/local/share/play-1.2.4" />
```

Now `build.xml` knows where my Play! is. Now I've just got to build fbconnect. (remember, I'm still in `/usr/local/share/play-1.2.4/modules`)

```
sudo ant
```

(You will need to have ant installed: http://ant.apache.org/)

I've still done the other configuration that you've done. Now when I start my Play! application, I'm getting a 'You need to configure fbconnect' error - which is what I expect, since I've not configured it. But it should work for you after configuration.

Hopefully the fbconnect maintainers will fix their installation, so that this won't be necessary in future, or perhaps both of us have somehow misunderstood the installation instructions and someone nice can tell us what we did wrong. But for now, this should get you working.

Good luck!

Comment: Good idea - I've submitted an issue report there. Thanks, C

Comment: Luckily this works.  Thanks!  The author appears to be OOC; maybe someone should fork his project and make the fix?

Comment: @craigmj I get the same error on windows 7. Can you help me to reslove this issue?